# Unstable symfony session when running codeception tests in github actions

Tags: symfony, github-actions, codeception

I'm running acceptance tests with Codeception in my Symfony app. When running the tests in Github actions, I frequently encounter errors where flash messages are not displayed or forms are failing due to CSRF errors.

I've tried adjusting the session settings and CSRF token settings in my Symfony configuration, but there are no fail when the tests are run on my local machine.

Are there any known issues in github actions related to symfony sessions?